# polymer 1.0 : how to store repetitive <style></style> section in another file?

Tags: styles, polymer-1.0

I have a few dom-modules all of which share some style lines in their style sections. So, I want to store those lines in the style section into another file and load in into my other elements. Any comment will be appreciated.

I know there is a style section in the polymer website, but it's too difficult to those without css background.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

### example-style.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- shared styles for all elements and index.html -->
<dom-module id="example-style"> <!-- -->
  <template>
    <style>
       <!-- insert styles here -->
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

### web-component-name.html

Add this line inside your custom webcomponent's template

```
<style include="example-style"></style>
```

Comment: Hi, Chris, that's exactly what I need. It's simple, but quite difficult to newbies. Thanks a lot.

Comment: something wrong. I though it works, but not. I moved  <style is="custom-style">...</style> into another html file called 'common-style.html', and wrote <link rel="import" href="../common-style.html"> ...<style is="common-style">...</style> instead. Why not work? Any idea?

Comment: Yup, it's beacuse you changed is="custom-style" to is="common-style"

Comment: That's only used for your index.html document. For custom elements use '<dom-module id="example-name">'  https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html

Comment: How to use both custom-style and my 'common-style'? Currently, my common-style uses custom-style, and my other elements needs my 'custom-style'. By the way, isn't it necessary to <link rel='import'  ...'custom-style.html> into other element's template?